# How many SQL jobs a sql server can handle?

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers, query-performance, sql-job

I am creating a database medical system and then I came to a point where I am trying to create a notification feature and i will use SQL jobs in it, where the SQL job responsibility is to check some tables and the entities that will find it need to be notified for a change in certain data will put their ids in an entity called `Notification` and a trigger will be called for the app to check that table and send the notificiation.

what I want to ask is how many SQL jobs can a sql server handle ?

Does the number of running SQL jobs in background affect the performance of my application or the database performance in a way or another ?

**NOTE:** the SQL job will run every 10 seconds

I couldn't find any useful information online.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems this link has a number of answers. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+max+number+of+jobs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1 As for the performance question, of course it will affect performance. Your job is presumably going to be executing queries against the database right? That means those queries are using resources on the server and locking tables when appropriate.

Comment: yes the job will be quering a joint sql query on an interval and store the appropriate in a new table so the app can look for that table only instead of making the joint by itself every time , is that okay or there must be another better way ?

Comment: I think you are looking at this backwards. Having a bunch of jobs would take up more space in msdb, etc... but performance wise if they aren't running, would you ever notice them? What if you had 1 job that ran every 10 seconds as opposed to 100 jobs that ran once a day. Which would have worse performance? Well one has more executions obviously, but what is the job doing? Performance is dependent on a lot here.

Comment: @scsimon the job will make a joint query and store the result in another table instead of the app doing it by itself. the app will then listen for a trigger and see the table only and send a notification to the users

Comment: Ahmed by the # of jobs isn't directly related to performance. What the jobs are doing and how frequently they are doing it is more of a concern here, generally speaking. 1 job doing index maintenance or dbcc checkdb could have a lot more of an affect than the rest of your jobs.

Comment: @scsimon i edited my question , i added that my job will run every 10 seconds

Comment: Still....the number and frequency running is not the only thing affecting performance. And quite frankly if you truly have a sql job running every 10 seconds you have designed something horribly wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange ok then my question need an answer because i want to know what will affect the performance to know if i need to change the whole design if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question really doesn't have enough background to get a definitive answer. What are the considerations?

1. Do the queries in your ten-second job actually complete in ten seconds, even when your DBMS is under its peak transactional workload? Obviously, if the job routinely doesn't complete in ten seconds, you'll get jobs piling up.
2. Do the queries in your job lock up tables and/or indexes so the transactional load can't run efficiently? (You should use `SET ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` as much as you can so database reads won't lock things unnecessarily.)
3. Do the queries in your job do a lot of rows' worth of inserts and updates, and so swamp the SQL Server transaction logs?
4. How big is your server? (CPU cores?  RAM? IO capacity?) How big is your database?
5. If your project succeeds and you get many users, will your answers to the above questions remain the same?  (Hint: no.)

You should spend some time on the execution plans for the queries in your job, and try to make them as efficient as possible.  Add the necessary indexes. If necessary refactor the queries to make them more efficient. SSMS will show you the execution plans and suggest appropriate indexes.

If your job is doing things like deleting expired rows, you may want to build the expiration in your data model.  For example, suppose your job does

```
 DELETE FROM readings WHERE expiration_date >= GETDATE()
```

and your application does this, relying on your job to avoid getting expired readings.

```
 SELECT something FROM readings
```

You can refactor your application query to say

```
 SELECT something FROM readings WHERE expiration_date < GETDATE()
```

and then run your job overnight, at a quiet time, rather than every ten seconds.

A ten-second job is not the greatest idea in the world. If you can rework your application so it will function correctly with a ten-second, ten-minute, or twelve-hour job, you'll have a more resilient production system. At any rate if something goes wrong with the job when your system is very busy you'll have more than ten seconds to fix it.

Comment: mmm i guess then i need to look to my erd and database designs . toa void sql jobs if applicable